# Activity is destroyed when another app from it, is opened with different orientation (android)

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-screen-support

I am developing a tablet application which has fixed orientation (Landscape), in which I import images from gallery.. when I open Gallery and select image from it, my app crashes...

it is happening only in that case, when my device is fixed with portrait orientation mode..
to resolve that i include following line in manifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

but still am not able to resolve my problem...

here is logcat

```
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357): Process: com.liam.simplereflect, PID: 21357
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start           activity ComponentInfo{com.liam.simplereflect/com.liam.simplereflect.General}:  java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.parse.ParseUser.checkApplicationContext(ParseUser.java:1041)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:842)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.findAsync(ParseQuery.java:520)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.find(ParseQuery.java:516)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.liam.simplereflect.General.getChildren_names_and_ids(General.java:1043)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at com.liam.simplereflect.General.onCreate(General.java:268)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-23 10:52:36.644: E/AndroidRuntime(21357):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you added config changes is all your activity in the manifest?... your error logs will be helpfull.

Comment: @NaveedAli you have class that extends parcelable?? if yes post it

Comment: Logcat says 'Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liam.simplereflect/com.liam.simplereflect.General}:  java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.' I doubt if this is due to orientation change.

Comment: code is working fine only due to the screen orientation, this problem is happening.. and it is happening in Nexus-7. I have testes it other devices lover than kitkat it just work fine..

Comment: @AtulOHolic no this is not the exact error. it is related with previous activity, that opens when this activity destroyed.